# Java SpringBoot - JDBCTemplate - Intermittent - TCP/IP Connection Error

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbctemplate, hikaricp

My app is Springboot built in Java connecting to SQLServer 2019 using JDBCTemplate and it's deployed in tomcat server.

Intermittently, I am getting below error

*Message failed processing :Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host XYZ, port xxxxx has failed. Error: "Connection refused (Connection refused). Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".*

I tried increasing connection pool but only error % is decreasing.

Configuration class looks like below:

```
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        var dS = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dS.setDriverClassName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        dS.setUrl(dbUrl);
        dS.setUsername(dbUserName);
        dS.setPassword(dbPassword);

        return dS;
    }
    @Bean
    public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate() {
        return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource());
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource());
    }

    @Bean("insertStoredProcedureCall")
    public SimpleJdbcCall insertStoredProcedureCall() {

        return new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate()).withSchemaName("x").withProcedureName("Add")
                .withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess()
                .declareParameters(new SqlParameter("ID", Types.INTEGER),
                        new SqlParameter("Name", Types.NVARCHAR));

    }
```

I have set hikari connection in property file

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime=20000 
spring.datasource.hikari.auto-commit=true 
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=5
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=50
spring.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout=30000
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=30000
spring.datasource.hikari.pool-name=TestHikari
```

DAO class looks like below

```
return namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sqlQuery, parameters,
new BeanPropertyRowMapper<TestEntity>(TestEntity.class));
```

Please let me know if am missing anything or I need to increase connection pool more?

Comment: I am not really sure if this is related to the connection pool, but rather you might have a bad internet connection that is cutting off intermittently and therefore the connection gets lost and unable to reconnect, and that is why you get those errors

Comment: Are you getting the error while trying to connect to DB via different threads ? Or is it when you are trying to run this program with a single Thread ? Trying bringing down your internet connection and then run your code with single thread. If you get the same error then probably it is because of internet connectivity as @SMA has highlighted.

Comment: @SMA and Ashish, the app is deployed in TEST server, running with multiple pods and yes it's a multithreaded app.

Comment: If this is an intermittent issue, (Meaning it happens sometimes), it is a network issue.  If it happens 100% of the time, it is still a network issue, but in this case its your cluster not having access to the Database server.

Comment: Thank you @SMA, I'll check on network.